# Save passwords to txt document and implement a list

Tags: python

My question is how can I implement a list within this program and make it so that when the user inputs a password it saves to a .txt document? I've tried but I can't make it work so this is the plain code that i need to add the feature too. Thanks for the help! The program also uses client/server but i haven't included that within this segment of my code as i didnt think it would be relevant. Thanks!

```
users = {}
status = ""

def displayMenu():
    status = input("Are you registered user? Please write yes or no. Press q to quit")

    if status == "yes":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "no":
        newUser()

def newUser():
   createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in users:
        print("\nLogin name already exist!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw
        print("\nUser created\n")

def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin successful! Your credentials have been saved.\n")
    else:
        print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")

while status != "q":
    displayMenu()
```

Comment: Do you have any code relating to opening / writing a file?

Comment: no i do not im afraid

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to learn about the Python file handling API. This is useful in all kinds of contexts, even for things that aren't strictly files. It's also good to know because it maps pretty directly to *nix's actual file handling operations, which will be useful in C and many other languages as well:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

If you want to store each user's password in a separate file, you can always just open it `"w"` (write mode), but if you want to be able to store them all in one file, you'll need to learn about how to search through and change particular lines, etc. Essentially, you'll be implementing your own file-backed database API. Sounds like a great learning project!